# box plot using column of different length

Tags: r, boxplot

I want to do some box plots, but I have data with a different number of rows for each column.
My data looks like:

```
OT1     OT2     OT3     OT4     OT5     OT6
22,6130653  16,6666667  20,259481   9,7431602   0,2777778   16,0678643
21,1122919  32,2946176  11,396648   10,9458023  4,7128509   10,8938547
23,5119048  19,5360195  23,9327541  39,5634921  0,6715507   12,2591613
16,9880885  39,5365943  7,7568134   22,7453205  3,6410445   11,7610063
            32,768937   25,2897351  9,6288027   4,1629535   3,7251656
            40,7819933              15,6320021  5,9171598   
            23,7961828              14,3728125  2,1887585
```

I'd like to have a box plot for each column (OT1, OT2…), but with the first three and the last three grouped together.
I tried:

```
>mydata <- read.csv('L5.txt', header = T, sep = "\t")
>mydata_t <- t(mydata)
>boxplot(mydata_t, ylab = "OTU abundance (%)",las=2, at=c(1,2,3 5,6,7))
```

But it didn't work…
How can I do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining both answers and extenting Henrik's answer, you can also group the OT's together in `boxplot()` as well:

[image]

```
dat <- read.table(text='OT1     OT2     OT3     OT4     OT5     OT6
22,6130653  16,6666667  20,259481   9,7431602   0,2777778   16,0678643
21,1122919  32,2946176  11,396648   10,9458023  4,7128509   10,8938547
23,5119048  19,5360195  23,9327541  39,5634921  0,6715507   12,2591613
16,9880885  39,5365943  7,7568134   22,7453205  3,6410445   11,7610063
            32,768937   25,2897351  9,6288027   4,1629535   3,7251656
            40,7819933              15,6320021  5,9171598   
            23,7961828              14,3728125  2,1887585',header=TRUE,fill=TRUE)

dat <- sapply(dat,function(x)as.numeric(gsub(',','.',x)))
dat.m <- melt(dat) 
dat.m <- transform(dat.m,group=ifelse(grepl('1|2|3','4|5|6'),
                                      'group1','group2')) 
as.factor(dat.m$X2)
 boxplot(dat.m$value~dat.m$X2,data=dat.m, 
        axes = FALSE, 
        at = 1:6 + c(0.2, 0, -0.2), 
        col = rainbow(6))
axis(side = 1, at = c(2, 5), labels = c("Group_1", "Group_2"))
axis(side = 2, at = seq(0, 40, by = 10))
legend("topright", legend = c("OT1", "OT2", "OT3", "OT4", "OT5", "OT6"), fill = rainbow(6))
abline(v = 3.5, col = "grey")
box()
```

Comment: +1 for the legend effort. It is always challenging to deal with legend in R basic plot.

Comment: thanks for the grafic @agstudy. Only forgot the box, but doesn't matter. :)

Comment: Hi loki and thanks for your help! I tried your code but when I run `dat.m <- transform(dat.m,group=ifelse(grep('1|2|3','4|5|6','7|8|9','10|11|12','13|14|15','16|17|18'),
+ 'group1','group2','group3','group4','group5','group6'))` (I have 18 columns in my complete dataset, so OT1 to OT18)
I had this error `Errore in ifelse(grep("1|2|3", "4|5|6", "7|8|9", "10|11|12", "13|14|15",  : 
  unused argument(s) ("group3", "group4", "group5", "group6")`

Comment: Can you also define the `Var2`?

Comment: @agstudy and I used `transform(dat.m, group = ifelse(grepl...` try this

Comment: I' m still having the same error... Maybe it's because I'm trying to use it with 6 groups... How can I modify it for using with 6 groups (OT1 to OT18)?

Comment: Normally it doesn't matter how many groups or (in your case) columns you want to put into `grepl()`. Have you cleaned your workspace to start with a "new" `dat.m`?

Comment: Yes I did all again, nd I'm still having the same problem. This is all the code I ran: `>dat <- read.table("boxplot_oraltypes_all.txt", header=T, fill=T)`
`> dat <- sapply(dat,function(x)as.numeric(gsub(',','.',x)))`
`> library(reshape)`
`> dat.m <- melt(dat)`
`> dat.m <- transform(dat.m,group=ifelse(grepl('1|2|3','4|5|6', '7|8|9', '10|11|12', '13|14|15', '16|17|18'),
+ 'group1', 'group2', 'group3', 'group4', 'group5', 'group6'))`
And the same error: `Errore in ifelse(grepl("1|2|3", "4|5|6", "7|8|9", "10|11|12", "13|14|15",  : 
  unused argument(s) ("group3", "group4", "group5", "group6")`

Comment: I could not figure out, what exactly is the problem with `grep()` and more than two groups but found a solution which worked.
`groups <- c("group1", "group2", "group3")

dat.m <- transform(dat.m, group = ifelse(grep(c('1|2','3|4', '5|6'),
                                      groups)))`

although there is the error message:
`Error in ifelse(grep(c("1|2", "3|4", "5|6"), groups)) : 
  argument "yes" is missing, with no default
In addition: Warning message:
In grep(c("1|2", "3|4", "5|6"), groups) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` 
it worked

Comment: You may try something more general, e.g.: `nr <- nrow(dat);` `nc <- ncol(dat);` `cols_per_grp <- 3;` `grp <- seq_len(nc/cols_per_grp);` `dat.m$group <- rep(grp, each = nr * cols_per_grp)`

grp <- seq_len(nc / cols_per_grp)
dat.m$group <- rep(grp, each = nr * cols_per_grp)

Comment: @loki: it worked! just two more things: I used `axis=TRUE` in the `boxplot` call and I saw that the names of the OTs are not in the order they were in the file (they are odered according to the number: OT1, OT10, OT11, then OT12, 3 and 14 and so on). How can I order them in the right way (OT1, 2, 3, then OT4, 5, 6, and so on up to OT16, 17 and 18)?

Comment: Second thing: how can I modify the distance between the boxes?

Comment: @Henrik: where do I have to put your code? after the call to `melt`? and after that, do I need just to call `boxplot`? do I have to modiy anything in the `boxplot` code?

Comment: It was just an alternative way to create the 'group' variable, instead of using `ifelse`.

Comment: @Henrik: It worked, but I have the same poblem: the columns are grouped in a wrong way (1, 11, 12, then 13,14,15 and so on)...

Comment: Well, you need to sort the 'Var2' column in 'dat.m' in the desired order.

Comment: if it is possible, I think it's the easiest to change the data in the textfile you read as data base. Change it to "OT01", "OT02, ...OT09, OT10, OT11... then they should be ordered right

Answer (score 3):

Not easy to group boxplots using R basic plots, better to use `ggplot2` here. Whatever the difficulty here is how to reformat your data and reshape them in the long format.

[image]

```
    dat <- read.table(text='OT1     OT2     OT3     OT4     OT5     OT6
22,6130653  16,6666667  20,259481   9,7431602   0,2777778   16,0678643
21,1122919  32,2946176  11,396648   10,9458023  4,7128509   10,8938547
23,5119048  19,5360195  23,9327541  39,5634921  0,6715507   12,2591613
16,9880885  39,5365943  7,7568134   22,7453205  3,6410445   11,7610063
            32,768937   25,2897351  9,6288027   4,1629535   3,7251656
            40,7819933              15,6320021  5,9171598   
            23,7961828              14,3728125  2,1887585',header=TRUE,fill=TRUE)
dat = sapply(dat,function(x)as.numeric(gsub(',','.',x))) 
dat.m <- melt(dat) 
dat.m <- transform(dat.m,group=ifelse(grepl('1|2|3',Var2),
   'group1','group2')) 
 ggplot(dat.m)+ 
     geom_boxplot(aes(x=group,y=value,fill=Var2))
```

Answer (score 3):

Or with `boxplot`, using @agstudy's 'dat':

```
df <- melt(dat)
boxplot(value ~ Var2, data = df, at = 1:6 + c(0.2, 0, -0.2))
```

[image]